# How to efficiently look up elements in a large vector

Tags: c++, c, vector

I have a `vector<unsigned>` of size `(90,000 * 9,000)`. I need to find many times whether an element exists in this vector or not?

For doing so, I stored the vector in a sorted form using `std::sort()` and then looked up elements in the vector using `std::binary_search()`. However on profiling using `perf` I find that looking up elements in `vector<unsigned>` is the slowest operation.

Can someone suggest some `data-structure` in `C/C++` which I can use to efficiently look up elements in a vector of `(90,000 * 9,000)` elements.

I perform insertion (bulk-insertion) only once. The rest of the times I perform only lookups, so the main overhead here is because of lookups.

Comment: Do you look for the same element multiple times? If so, you can cache the result.

Comment: What type of data the vector has ?

Comment: To provide a meaningful answer, we would need to know the other constraints - for instance. the expected performance of insertion (and if used, removal) operations.

Comment: A trie should be faster if you can organize your data that way.

Comment: The binary search will need log_{2}(81e7)  ~= 30 steps at most. Are you sure that size is your problem?

Comment: Perhaps the `90.000 * 9000` hints at a vector of vectors? Micha is right, a binary search on a 1D vector can be quite hard to beat. Possibly `std::unordered_set< >` (hash table) ?

Comment: @Jagannath vector has unsigned elements

Comment: @marko I perform insertion (bulk-insertion) only once. The rest of the times I perform only lookups, so the main overhead here is because of lookups

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Time and again performing binary search is a problem..as I need to perform binary search a million times

Comment: @MSalters * implies multiplication. It is a 1 D array of size 90,000 multiplied by 9,000 elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got 810 million values out of 4 billion possible values (assuming 32 bits `unsigned`). That's 1/5th of the total range, and uses 3.2 GB. This means you're in fact better of with a `std::vector<bool>` with 4 billion bits. This gives you O(1) lookup in less space (0.5 GB).

(In theory, `unsigned` could be 16 bits. `unsigned long` is *at least* 32 bits, `std::uint32_t` might be what you want)

Comment: I am not able to understand how can I use std::vector<bool>

Comment: @StegVerner: Simple: you start with a vector of `UNIT_MAX` values, all false. To insert 42, you set `v[42]=true`. To remove 42, `v[42]=false`. To check if 42 is present,  `if (v[42])`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the actual data structure of the vector the `contains` operation may take an `O(n)` or `O(1)`. Usually, it's `O(N)` if vector is backed by either associative array or linked list, in this case `contains` will be a full scan in the worst case scenario. You have mitigated a full scan by ordering and using binary search, which is `O(log (N))`. `Log N` is pretty good complexity with only `O(1)` being better. So your choice is either:

- Cache look up result for the items, this might be a good compromise if you have many repetitions of the same element
- Replace vector with another data structure with efficient `contains` operation such as the one based on a [hashtable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) or [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). Note you may loose other features, such as ordering of items
- Use two data structures, one for `contains` operations and original vector for whatever you use it for
- Use a third data structure that offers a compromise, for example a data structure that work well with [bloom filter](https://code.google.com/p/bloom/)

Comment: The question specifies binary_search, which is neither O(1) or O(N) but O(log N). Also, `vector` is backed by contiguous memory, not an associative array or a linked list.

Comment: No, the question doesn't say that. The question is, I qoute:  *"I need to find many times whether an element exists in this vector or not?"*. Binary search is the solution that OP attempted and indeed binary search is `O(logN)`, but he can do it in `O(1)` with a hashtable, which is what I suggested as one of the options.

Answer (score 2):

> However on profiling using perf I find that looking up elements in
>   vector is the slowest operation.

That is half of the information you need, the other half being ***"how fast is it compared to other algorithms/containers"***? Maybe using `std::vector<>` is actually the fastest, or maybe its the slowest. To find you'll have to benchmark/profile a few different designs.

For example, the following are *very naive* benchmarks using random integers on 1000x9000 sized containers (I would get seg-faults on larger sizes for the maps, assumably a limit of 32-bit memory).

If you need a count of non-unique integers:

- `std::vector<unsigned>` = **500 ms**
- `std::map<unsigned, unsigned>` = **1700 ms**
- `std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned>` = **3700 ms**

If you just need to test for the presence of unique integers:

- `std::vector<bool>` = **15 ms**
- `std::bitset<>` = **50 ms**
- `std::set<unsigned>` = **350 ms**

Note that we're not too interested in the exact values but rather the relative comparisons between containers. `std::map<>` is relatively slow which is not surprising given the number of dynamic allocations and non-locality of the data involved. The bitsets are by far the fastest but don't work if need the counts of non-unique integers.

I would suggest doing a similar benchmark using your exact container sizes and contents, both of which may well affect the benchmark results. It may turn out that `std::vector<>` may be the best solution after all but now you have some data to back up that design choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need iterate through the collection (in a sorted manner) since c++11 you could use `std::unordered_set<yourtype>` all you need to do is to provide the collection way of getting hashing and equality information for `yourtype`. The time of accessing element of the collection is here amortised O(1), unlike sorted vector where it's O(log(n)).

Comment: I wondered about the 90,000 * 9000 requirement and whether this implied that the vector was being used as a 2d array - in which case, the index of the element might be what is being found.

Comment: @marko yes you're right in this case it may be worth to change the unordered_map templated parameters to e.g. `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, sometype>`

Comment: @marko The vector being used is a 1-D array. * stands for multiplication..:)

Comment: I think you don't want a `map` but a `set` - there's no key/value separation.

Comment: Using `boost::multi_index` might be an option too using both `random_access_index` and `hashed_index` as indices.  You get O(1) conversion between index types - so in this case we'd use the hash_index to find the item in close to  O(1) and covert back to array index (also  O(1)).

Comment: If he is using a binary_search lookup time will already be O(log n) so map and set will not be fast. If anything it will be slow due to less localized memory. An unordered_set should be faster though.

Comment: @doron: A binary search doesn't have locality of reference on a `std::vector`, precisely because the vector is contiguous and the binary search only accesses adjacent elements in the very last step.

Comment: @MSalters - given the size of the vector, you are right.